# Endless scrolling after preforming returns on first item

Tags: java, android

I have endless scrolling implemented on receyclerview and it's working fine. After I reach last item, across internet connection I get the data from second webiste page and populate the adapter and displayed data inside the app. But the problem is after download of new data is finished I'm always returned on first item, so I have to scroll down to see last downloaded items. I tried with `notifyItemInserted(position)` but that didn't help. So my question is why is that happening?

I tried to find the solution on internet but didn't find anything useful. Thanks.

Comment: how do you display newly added data, in the same recyclerview Activity/fragment? or in a separated view or do you merge both ? and how do you manage calls, should the second call be requested after the first response is retrieved ? please clarify and add your code

Comment: @AhmadAlsanie I'm executing the asynctask again just providing a new url in doinbackground method I think problem is there somewhere, but just a minute I will add the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are recreating you Adapter each time when new data is come.You should use the same adapter, add new data to previous list and call notifyDataSetChange()